# In template How to print a link from a route name

Tags: php, routes, slim

I would like display a link using a route name (**home**) into my template.
How can I do with Slim Framework
Thanks

My route

```
<?php
// index : home
$app->get('/home', function () use ($app){
   $app->render('home.php');
})->name('home');
```

My template

```
<div>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->tr("home"); // This doesn't work ?>">my home link</a>
</div>
```

or with **urlFor()**

```
<div>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->urlFor("home"); // This doesn't work ?>">my home link</a>
</div>
```

I got this message

```
=> Call to undefined method Slim\View::urlFor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

just add this

```
$app->hook('slim.before.router', function () use ($app) { 
    // Pass in the App so we can use urlFor() to generate routes 
    $app->view()->setData('app', $app); 
});
```

An then into your template you can use this (with ***app*** not ***this***):

```
<div>
  <a href="<?php echo $app->urlFor("home"); ?>">my home link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Slim instance is accessible through a Singleton and its `getInstance` method

```
<a href="<?php echo Slim\Slim::getInstance()->urlFor('home'); ?>">my home link</a>
```

You can also specify a name if you have multiple instances of Slim

```
<a href="<?php echo Slim\Slim::getInstance('blog')->urlFor('home'); ?>">my home link</a>
```

If you want to access the urlFor method using `$this`

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->urlFor("home");">my home link</a>
```

Then you should create a Custom View by adding a subclass of `Slim\View` containing a `urlFor` method and link it to Slim

Custom class :

```
<?php
class CustomView extends \Slim\View
{
    public function urlFor($name, $params = array(), $appName = 'default')
    {
        return Slim::getInstance($appName)->urlFor($name, $params);
    }
}
```

Linking :

```
<?php
require 'CustomView.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new CustomView()
));
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
echo '<a href="' . Slim\Slim::getInstance()->urlFor('home') . '">home</a>';
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your answer.